# Iterate over array in reverse order

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I have the following loop -

```
for (var key in counts) {

    var entry = counts[key];

    for (var entryKey in entry) {

        arrOfCounts.push(entry[entryKey]);

    }
}
```

I wish to iterate over `counts` in a reverse order, I tried the following -

```
for (var i = counts.length; i > 0; --i) {
}
```

However my array although it has three indexes, their values are dates and therefore it has no length.

Comment: Is `counts` an *object*? Then it has no order to begin with.

Comment: All "arrays" have a length, but do note that indexes in Javascript are *based on zero*, meaning the last index is `counts.length - 1`.

Comment: As always with such questions, give the input and desired output. A non-functioning piece of code is not enough, or will at least hinder people from answering quickly.

Comment: `counts.reverse().forEach(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `counts` is an object, try this way.

```
for (var i = Object.keys(counts).length; i > 0; --i) {
}
```

Comment: 1) That by itself doesn't help to access a key or value, 2) there is no order to begin with, so iterating in "reverse" order is just as arbitrary and random as "forward".

Comment: @deceze `var value = counts[Object.keys(ob)[i-1]]`; this will work.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer for 2022

Hello, from the future. I'm sure you've forgotten about this question by now and could answer it in your sleep if you needed to, but I'm going to add an answer to help anyone else who might stumble upon it because a lot has changed since the question was asked.

### Array vs Object

First, there seems to be some confusion in the question about the data structure in use. In JavaScript, object keys are not guaranteed to have an order. Therefore, there is no guaranteed reverse order. Even if you use `Object.keys` to produce what looks like a sorted list, you can't rely upon it. In fact, you'll see from [MDN's examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) that it tends to be sorted in the order the keys were initially provided. Essentially, an Object is an unordered data structure. The reason the length of the object is zero (or undefined) is because it has no length. It's not because the properties are dates.

An array, on the other hand, is an ordered data type. You can easily reverse an array by calling `Array.prototype.reverse()`. But you don't have an array. You have an object.

### Solution

The easiest way to solve your problem is to create an array and sort it.

Convert the object into an array:

```js
const arr = Object.entries(counts);
```

This gives us an array of tuples where the first element is the key and the second is the value. You can access the key the same way you would access the first element of an array.

Sort the array in reverse alphabetical order by the keys (change `a[0] < b[0]` to whatever comparison you want to make and read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for more details):

```js
arr.sort((a,b) => b[0].localeCompare(a[0]));
```

Now you can iterate it:

```js
for (const v of arr) {
  console.log(`Element has these properties: ${Object.keys(v).join(', '}`);
}
```

Side note: if you already have an array and you want to get it in reverse order, just use `Array.prototype.reverse()`.

```js
console.log(arr.reverse());
```